# CSS grid let an item take the rest of available screen space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am currently working on a grid layout with something like that:

[image]

But the content is overflowing so my whole grid would always resize. But I want the sidebar and header to be fixed so that only the content is scrollable. This works if I give the content a fixed height, but I am not quite sure how I give it the remaining height after the header (the header doesn't have a fixed height because of word-breaks on mobile).

So I need something like the header being "fit-conent" and the content "take-remaining-screen-space".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the body overflow hidden, and content overflow-y auto (or scroll). With given size for left and top

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(114, 248, 30, 0.5);
}

#div2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(154, 237, 192, 0.5);
}

#div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(91, 183, 194, 0.5);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```