# CSS Grid: Make grid row fill the screen, pushing next rows offscreen

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way to do this through pure HTML/CSS? This is what I want to accomplish:

```
|---------------------------| <-- start of screen
|          header           |   fixed height
|---------------------------|
|                           |
|                           |
|          content          |   fill screen
|                           |
|                           |
|---------------------------| <-- end of screen
|          footer           |   auto
|---------------------------|
```

Some stuff I've seen but doesn't answer my question:

[CSS grid let an item take the rest of available screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969014/css-grid-let-an-item-take-the-rest-of-available-screen-space)

[How to make CSS Grid with fixed header and footer with remainder in middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124414/how-to-make-css-grid-with-fixed-header-and-footer-with-remainder-in-middle)

[How to make CSS Grid items take up remaining space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799207/how-to-make-css-grid-items-take-up-remaining-space)

[Here's what I have so far (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPx5T.png)

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: gray;
}

.app-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header header"
        "contnt contnt contnt contnt"
        "footer footer footer footer"
    ;

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

.content {
    grid-area: contnt;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="app-wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            header
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this with CSS Grid unless you wrap the header and main in a separate div

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks! It honestly slipped my mind. I'll just wrap it then make sure its at 100vh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the last row equal to `0` and also define a height on the footer to override the effect of `0`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.app-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 0; /* 0 for the last row */
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.content {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: min-content; /* overide the 0 of the row */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Remarkable answer.... absolutely ingenious.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Wrap `header` and `content` then make it have 100vh.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: gray;
}

.facade-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header header"
        "contnt contnt contnt contnt"
    ;

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

.content {
    grid-area: contnt;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="app-wrapper">
        <div class="facade-wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                header
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

here is my simplest solution, I used calc function to subtract the height of the header section so that content div could take up the remaining space.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.container{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
.header{
  height:60px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}
.content{
  height:calc(100vh - 60px);
  background-color:yellow;
}
.footer{
   background-color:red;
  color:white;
}
```

**Working demo**
https://codepen.io/Rohan-Kadam/pen/vYbQQdm